# <header> element will not float right

Tags: html, header, css-float

somehow my header element with the navigation won't float to the right top corner with a position:fixed.

Anybody with ideas?

I'm really looking forward to answer for this little mystery.

Here's the code:

```
<header class="hidden" style="z-index:40000; float:right;"> 
  <div class="wrapper hidden" id="test"> 
    <nav class="work-nav menu">
      <ul class="navscroll">
        <a href="#headerwrap" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Home">
          <li><img src="img/nav_bar_home_02.png"></li>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.designlike.de/g_website_test/work-overview.htm" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" class="transition" title="Work">
          <li><img src="img/nav_bar_work_02.png"></li>
        </a>
        <a href="#footerscroll" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Contact">
          <li><img src="img/nav_bar_contact_02.png"></li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div> 
</header>
```

And the css:

```
/* ------ */
/* HEADER */
/* ------ */
header {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;
    overflow:visible;
    z-index:20000;
    float:right; !important
}
header .wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    float:right;
}
nav {  
    float:right;
    width:40px;
    margin-top:-1px; 
}
nav ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; position:fixed;}
nav ul li {
    width:40px;
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color:#ffd200;
    margin-top:1px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    width:40px;
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color:#2a2a2a;
} 

nav a {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100%;
}

nav a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav li:hover {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: -1, I clicked your link, it appears to be spam and nothing to do with this question.  You might try tagging this html5 and adding a short code sample somewhere.

Comment: Edited my initial post: Sorry, here's the code from my html that concerns my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `position: fixed;` with `float: right;`. One of them is telling it to exist at a specific pixel location, whereas the other is telling it to float right in its container. They're conflicting directives, and `position` is going to win.

That said, I believe you can achieve what you're trying by simply changing `left: 0` to `right: 0` and removing the `float` altogether.

Comment: Saw this answer pop up just as I was typing something similar. You were faster :D Also, this is wrong float:right; !important, the correct syntax would be float:right !important;

Comment: Since you're new, a quick note on SO etiquette: if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!